# Magento 2 menu not showing new added category

Tags: magento

I added category and subcategory to magento 2 and after that I finished. I reindexed and flushed cash but nothing appears on the website frontend - only the old categories. I tried many times clearing cash and reindexing but it was in vain. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain bit more what are you trying to say with code ? Please take some time to read the help page, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times is because your store is only looking to the old category. you have to enter to Stores->All Stores, then select the middle one and change the category from there. Hope it helps.